# .NET: How do you indicate a inherited property is not implemented?

Tags: .net

In the get section of the inherited property, you could throw a NotImplementedException. But what to do with the set section?

Comment: There really is no nice way to *not* implement something :( Someone somewhere is going to get upset if they expect it and it doesn't work because it "just doesn't work" or throws an exception.. perhaps look at it differently: what are *consequences* of not implementing such property?

Comment: @pst: I guess it's still better than them finding out themselves after writing a lot of code?

Comment: ///<remarks>This method is not implemented</remarks>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mark the property obsolete, like so:

```
[Obsolete("This property is not implemented", true)]
public new int SomeProperty
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

That way users will get an error if they try to use the property. You could also add an `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` attribute to hide the property from intellisense, but [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx#Y200) "in Visual C#, EditorBrowsableAttribute does not suppress members from a class in the same assembly." So I'm not sure if that would be of much help.